# select2_from_ajax with custom JSON

Tags: laravel-backpack

Im trying to create a custom AJAX search call without using a model relationship in Laravel Backpack.

For example I have a function that takes the AJAX query and returns JSON formatted data for the select.

However it seems like this requires a model relationship, is it possible to make an AJAX search call without using a model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the present moment the only solution to use the `select2_from_ajax` without a real model that I am aware is to use a "fake model" using [Laravel Sushi package](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi).

You can wrap your data into those fake models and use them as the "model" in the field.

Cheers